# Eclipse opens different source file than the editable one

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

When I run an application into eclipse, if an exception is thrown and is showed in the console, then you are able to click on the links which takes you to the source code file.

Fine, the problem is that when I click those links they open as external uneditable resources (different icon in the editor tab, Java source files have a blue J but these files have the J empty, only showing the border). Same problem when debugging, the files opened are not the same tabs as the ones edited.

For more information, while the normal source files shows in the title bar something like:

```
project/path/to/source/file.java
```

The others show its complete path:

```
C:\absolut\path\to\source\file.java
```

This is quite annoying since I have to go and back from one to the other and I have no idea where to change this or why it is happening (it was alright a time ago).

Any hints on how to edit this?
Thanks

Comment: "Java source files have a blue J but these files have the J empty" Are you referring to class files?

Comment: I refer to the icon shown in the tab of the files, in the editor. Edited the question to reflect this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a classpath problem. When you click, you are actually accessing the file from the classpath.

To view the Java file, you have to add a reference to your project in the classpath and move it to the top of the classpath list.

Comment: That was exactly the problem: replace the .jar file in the classpath for the project itself. Thanks (to do this: Run Configurations...)

Comment: you're welcome (It happened to me before). Always check the path of the file you are seeing because it will indicate where it is getting the file from

Answer (score 0):

You can also try converting it to project facets java version, right click on project --> properties --> choose Project Facets -->java 1.7 or [your version]. Apply.