# Eclipse console error link sending me to wrong project

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

I have a web site project in Eclipse and I needed to copy it and rename it for a new client. So I had my tortisesvn export the site to a new directory and changed the project name in the .project file and imported it into the same workspace in Eclipse. It seems to be running ok but now when I get errors in the console window the links that should take me to the line of the error take me to the file in the original project not the new one. Anybody know what I can do to fix this?

EDIT: In case anyone asks. I'm sure it's using the correct file when running the site and the error number is on the correct line. I put an intentional divide by 0 error in my code to test this and I get the expected error in the console window on the line that the error is on but it still sends me to the same file name but in the other project.

Comment: Are your trying to run the program in debug mobe??

Comment: I haven't yet. I attached the copied project to a server in Eclipse (the same server the original site is attached to). I'm talking about the log file you see in "console" when I start the server and run into an error. It's also where system.println would go.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one with some more searching: [Eclipse opens wrong source file on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200245/eclipse-opens-wrong-source-file-on-exception)

It seems if I remove the other project from the server in tomcat it goes to the correct spot. What a pain.